# What is the ideal image for tesseract library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ocr

I am doing OCR in my project using tesseract . I have used images with 72 dpi .But it is given me output far from accuracy . I have read somewhere that it is well to give input above 200 dpi. But what is the standard image configurations i.e. size, dpi, file format etc for tesseract library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the second part of my answer due to character limit..

here is the .mm

.m

```
/*
 *  Image.cpp
 *  ImageProcessing
 *
 *  
 *
 */
#include "Image.h"
#include <stack>

@implementation ImageWrapper

@synthesize image;
@synthesize ownsImage;

+ (ImageWrapper *) imageWithCPPImage:(Image *) theImage;
{
    ImageWrapper *wrapper = [[ImageWrapper alloc] init];
    wrapper.image=theImage;
    wrapper.ownsImage=true;
    return [wrapper autorelease];
}

+ (ImageWrapper *) imageWithCPPImage:(Image *) theImage ownsImage:(bool) ownsTheImage;
{
    ImageWrapper *wrapper = [[ImageWrapper alloc] init];
    wrapper.image=theImage;
    wrapper.ownsImage=ownsTheImage;
    return [wrapper autorelease];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    // delete the image that we have been holding onto
    if(ownsImage) delete image;
    [super dealloc];
}


@end

void Image::initYptrs() {
    m_yptrs=(uint8_t **) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t *)*m_height);
    for(int i=0; i<m_height; i++) {
        m_yptrs[i]=m_imageData+i*m_width;
    }
}


Image::Image(ImageWrapper *other, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    m_width=x2-x1;
    m_height=y2-y1;
    m_imageData=(uint8_t *) malloc(m_width*m_height);
    initYptrs();
    Image *otherImage=other.image;
    for(int y=y1; y<y2; y++) {
        for(int x=x1; x<x2; x++) {
            (*this)[y-y1][x-x1]=(*otherImage)[y][x];
        }
    }
    m_ownsData=true;
}

Image::Image(int width, int height) {
    m_imageData=(uint8_t *) malloc(width*height);
    m_width=width;
    m_height=height;
    m_ownsData=true;
    initYptrs();
}
// create an image from data
Image::Image(uint8_t *imageData, int width, int height, bool ownsData) {
    m_imageData=imageData;
    m_width=width;
    m_height=height;
    m_ownsData=ownsData;
    initYptrs();
}

Image::Image(UIImage *srcImage, int width, int height,  CGInterpolationQuality interpolation, bool imageIsRotatedBy90degrees) {
    if(imageIsRotatedBy90degrees) {
        int tmp=width;
        width=height;
        height=tmp;
    }
    m_width=width;
    m_height=height;
    // get hold of the image bytes
    m_imageData=(uint8_t *) malloc(m_width*m_height);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef context=CGBitmapContextCreate(m_imageData,  m_width, m_height, 8, m_width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, interpolation);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0, m_width, m_height), [srcImage CGImage]);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    if(imageIsRotatedBy90degrees) {
        uint8_t *tmpImage=(uint8_t *) malloc(m_width*m_height);
        for(int y=0; y<m_height; y++) {
            for(int x=0; x<m_width; x++) {
                tmpImage[x*m_height+y]=m_imageData[(m_height-y-1)*m_width+x];
            }
        }
        int tmp=m_width;
        m_width=m_height;
        m_height=tmp;
        free(m_imageData);
        m_imageData=tmpImage;
    }
    initYptrs();
}

void Image::normalise() {
    int min=INT_MAX;
    int max=0;

    for(int i=0; i<m_width*m_height; i++) {
        if(m_imageData[i]>max) max=m_imageData[i];
        if(m_imageData[i]<min) min=m_imageData[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<m_width*m_height; i++) {
        m_imageData[i]=255*(m_imageData[i]-min)/(max-min);
    }
}


// copy a section of another image
ImageWrapper *Image::createImage(ImageWrapper *other, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    return [ImageWrapper imageWithCPPImage:new Image(other, x1, y1, x2, y2)];
}
// create an empty image of the required width and height
ImageWrapper *Image::createImage(int width, int height) {
    return [ImageWrapper imageWithCPPImage:new Image(width, height)];
}
// create an image from data
ImageWrapper *Image::createImage(uint8_t *imageData, int width, int height, bool ownsData) {
    return [ImageWrapper imageWithCPPImage:new Image(imageData, width, height, ownsData)];
}
// take a source UIImage and convert it to greyscale
ImageWrapper *Image::createImage(UIImage *srcImage, int width, int height, bool imageIsRotatedBy90degrees) {
    return [ImageWrapper imageWithCPPImage:new Image(srcImage, width, height, kCGInterpolationHigh, imageIsRotatedBy90degrees)];
}

void Image::extractConnectedRegion(int x, int y, std::vector<ImagePoint> *points) {
    (*points).push_back(ImagePoint(x,y));
    (*this)[y][x]=0;
    int left, right;
    left=x-1;
    right=x+1;
    while(left>=0 && (*this)[y][left]!=0) {
        (*this)[y][left]=0;
        (*points).push_back(ImagePoint(left,y));        
        left--;
    }
    while(right<m_width && (*this)[y][right]!=0) {
        (*this)[y][right]=0;
        (*points).push_back(ImagePoint(right,y));       
        right++;
    }
    for(int i=left; i<=right; i++) {
        if(i>=0 && i<m_width) {
            if(y>0 && (*this)[y-1][i]!=0) {
                extractConnectedRegion(i, y-1, points);
            }
            if(y<(m_height-1) && (*this)[y+1][i]!=0) {
                extractConnectedRegion(i, y+1, points);
            }
        }
    }
}

inline int findThresholdAtPosition(int startx, int starty, int size, Image* src) {
    int total=0;
    for(int y=starty; y<starty+size; y++) {
        for(int x=startx; x<startx+size; x++) {
            total+=(*src)[y][x];
        }
    }
    int threshold=total/(size*size);
    return threshold;
};

/*
ImageWrapper* Image::autoLocalThreshold() {
    const int local_size=10;
    // now produce the thresholded image
    Image *result=new Image(m_width, m_height);
    // process the image
    int threshold=0;
    for(int y=local_size/2; y<m_height-local_size/2; y++) {
        for(int x=local_size/2; x<m_width-local_size/2; x++) {
            threshold=findThresholdAtPosition(x-local_size/2, y-local_size/2, local_size, this);
            int val=(*this)[y][x];
            if(val>threshold*0.9)
                    (*result)[y][x]=0;
                else
                    (*result)[y][x]=255;
        }
    }
    return [ImageWrapper imageWithCPPImage:result];
}
*/


ImageWrapper* Image::autoLocalThreshold() {
    const int local_size=8;
    // now produce the thresholded image
    uint8_t *result=(uint8_t*) malloc(m_width*m_height);
    // get the initial total
    int total=0;
    for(int y=0; y<local_size; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<local_size; x++) {
            total+=(*this)[y][x];
        }
    }
    // process the image
    int lastIndex=m_width*m_height-(m_width*local_size/2+local_size/2);
    for(int index=m_width*local_size/2+local_size/2; index<lastIndex; index++) {
        int threshold=total/64;
        if(m_imageData[index]>threshold*0.9)
            result[index]=0;
        else
            result[index]=255;
        // calculate the new total
        for(int index2=index-m_width*local_size/2-local_size/2; index2<index+m_width*local_size/2-local_size/2; index2+=m_width) {
            total-=m_imageData[index2];
            total+=m_imageData[index2+local_size];
        }
    }
    return Image::createImage(result, m_width, m_height, true);
}

ImageWrapper *Image::autoThreshold() {
    int total=0;
    int count=0;
    for(int y=0; y<m_height; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<m_width; x++) {
            total+=(*this)[y][x];
            count++;
        }
    }
    int threshold=total/count;
    Image *result=new Image(m_width, m_height);
    for(int y=0; y<m_height; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<m_width; x++) {
            if((*this)[y][x]>threshold*0.8) {
                (*result)[y][x]=0;
            } else {
                (*result)[y][x]=255;
            }
        }
    }
    return [ImageWrapper imageWithCPPImage:result];
}

#define NOEDGE 255
#define POSSIBLE_EDGE 128
#define EDGE 0

void non_max_supp(int *mag, int *gradx, int *grady, int nrows, int ncols,
             uint8_t *result) 
{
    int rowcount, colcount,count;
    int *magrowptr,*magptr;
    int *gxrowptr,*gxptr;
    int *gyrowptr,*gyptr,z1,z2;
    int m00,gx,gy;
    float mag1,mag2,xperp,yperp;
    uint8_t *resultrowptr, *resultptr;


    /****************************************************************************
     * Zero the edges of the result image.
     ****************************************************************************/
    for(count=0,resultrowptr=result,resultptr=result+ncols*(nrows-1); 
        count<ncols; resultptr++,resultrowptr++,count++){
        *resultrowptr = *resultptr = (unsigned char) 0;
    }

    for(count=0,resultptr=result,resultrowptr=result+ncols-1;
        count<nrows; count++,resultptr+=ncols,resultrowptr+=ncols){
        *resultptr = *resultrowptr = (unsigned char) 0;
    }

    /****************************************************************************
     * Suppress non-maximum points.
     ****************************************************************************/
    for(rowcount=1,magrowptr=mag+ncols+1,gxrowptr=gradx+ncols+1,
        gyrowptr=grady+ncols+1,resultrowptr=result+ncols+1;
        rowcount<nrows-2; 
        rowcount++,magrowptr+=ncols,gyrowptr+=ncols,gxrowptr+=ncols,
        resultrowptr+=ncols){   
        for(colcount=1,magptr=magrowptr,gxptr=gxrowptr,gyptr=gyrowptr,
            resultptr=resultrowptr;colcount<ncols-2; 
            colcount++,magptr++,gxptr++,gyptr++,resultptr++){   
            m00 = *magptr;
            if(m00 == 0){
                *resultptr = (unsigned char) NOEDGE;
            }
            else{
                xperp = -(gx = *gxptr)/((float)m00);
                yperp = (gy = *gyptr)/((float)m00);
            }

            if(gx >= 0){
                if(gy >= 0){
                    if (gx >= gy)
                    {  
                        /* 111 */
                        /* Left point */
                        z1 = *(magptr - 1);
                        z2 = *(magptr - ncols - 1);

                        mag1 = (m00 - z1)*xperp + (z2 - z1)*yperp;

                        /* Right point */
                        z1 = *(magptr + 1);
                        z2 = *(magptr + ncols + 1);

                        mag2 = (m00 - z1)*xperp + (z2 - z1)*yperp;
                    }
                    else
                    {    
                        /* 110 */
                        /* Left point */
                        z1 = *(magptr - ncols);
                        z2 = *(magptr - ncols - 1);

                        mag1 = (z1 - z2)*xperp + (z1 - m00)*yperp;

                        /* Right point */
                        z1 = *(magptr + ncols);
                        z2 = *(magptr + ncols + 1);

                        mag2 = (z1 - z2)*xperp + (z1 - m00)*yperp; 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (gx >= -gy)
                    {
                        /* 101 */
                        /* Left point */
                        z1 = *(magptr - 1);
                        z2 = *(magptr + ncols - 1);

                        mag1 = (m00 - z1)*xperp + (z1 - z2)*yperp;

                        /* Right point */
                        z1 = *(magptr + 1);
                        z2 = *(magptr - ncols + 1);

                        mag2 = (m00 - z1)*xperp + (z1 - z2)*yperp;
                    }
                    else
                    {    
                        /* 100 */
                        /* Left point */
                        z1 = *(magptr + ncols);
                        z2 = *(magptr + ncols - 1);

                        mag1 = (z1 - z2)*xperp + (m00 - z1)*yperp;

                        /* Right point */
                        z1 = *(magptr - ncols);
                        z2 = *(magptr - ncols + 1);

                        mag2 = (z1 - z2)*xperp  + (m00 - z1)*yperp; 
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((gy = *gyptr) >= 0)
                {
                    if (-gx >= gy)
                    {          
                        /* 011 */
                        /* Left point */
                        z1 = *(magptr + 1);
                        z2 = *(magptr - ncols + 1);

                        mag1 = (z1 - m00)*xperp + (z2 - z1)*yperp;

                        /* Right point */
                        z1 = *(magptr - 1);
                        z2 = *(magptr + ncols - 1);

                        mag2 = (z1 - m00)*xperp + (z2 - z1)*yperp;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* 010 */
                        /* Left point */
                        z1 = *(magptr - ncols);
                        z2 = *(magptr - ncols + 1);

                        mag1 = (z2 - z1)*xperp + (z1 - m00)*yperp;

                        /* Right point */
                        z1 = *(magptr + ncols);
                        z2 = *(magptr + ncols - 1);

                        mag2 = (z2 - z1)*xperp + (z1 - m00)*yperp;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (-gx > -gy)
                    {
                        /* 001 */
                        /* Left point */
                        z1 = *(magptr + 1);
                        z2 = *(magptr + ncols + 1);

                        mag1 = (z1 - m00)*xperp + (z1 - z2)*yperp;

                        /* Right point */
                        z1 = *(magptr - 1);
                        z2 = *(magptr - ncols - 1);

                        mag2 = (z1 - m00)*xperp + (z1 - z2)*yperp;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* 000 */
                        /* Left point */
                        z1 = *(magptr + ncols);
                        z2 = *(magptr + ncols + 1);

                        mag1 = (z2 - z1)*xperp + (m00 - z1)*yperp;

                        /* Right point */
                        z1 = *(magptr - ncols);
                        z2 = *(magptr - ncols - 1);

                        mag2 = (z2 - z1)*xperp + (m00 - z1)*yperp;
                    }
                }
            } 

            /* Now determine if the current point is a maximum point */

            if ((mag1 > 0.0) || (mag2 > 0.0))
            {
                *resultptr = (unsigned char) NOEDGE;
            }
            else
            {    
                if (mag2 == 0.0)
                    *resultptr = (unsigned char) NOEDGE;
                else
                    *resultptr = (unsigned char) POSSIBLE_EDGE;
            }
        } 
    }
}

void follow_edges(uint8_t *edgemapptr, int *edgemagptr, short lowval,
             int cols)
{
    int *tempmagptr;
    uint8_t *tempmapptr;
    int i;
    int x[8] = {1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1},
    y[8] = {0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1};

    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        tempmapptr = edgemapptr - y[i]*cols + x[i];
        tempmagptr = edgemagptr - y[i]*cols + x[i];

        if((*tempmapptr == POSSIBLE_EDGE) && (*tempmagptr > lowval)){
            *tempmapptr = (unsigned char) EDGE;
            follow_edges(tempmapptr,tempmagptr, lowval, cols);
        }
    }
}

void apply_hysteresis(int *mag, uint8_t *nms, int rows, int cols,
                      float tlow, float thigh, uint8_t *edge)
{
    int r, c, pos, numedges, highcount, lowthreshold, highthreshold,hist[32768];
    int maximum_mag;

    /****************************************************************************
     * Initialize the edge map to possible edges everywhere the non-maximal
     * suppression suggested there could be an edge except for the border. At
     * the border we say there can not be an edge because it makes the
     * follow_edges algorithm more efficient to not worry about tracking an
     * edge off the side of the image.
     ****************************************************************************/
    for(r=0,pos=0;r<rows;r++){
        for(c=0;c<cols;c++,pos++){
            if(nms[pos] == POSSIBLE_EDGE) edge[pos] = POSSIBLE_EDGE;
            else edge[pos] = NOEDGE;
        }
    }

    for(r=0,pos=0;r<rows;r++,pos+=cols){
        edge[pos] = NOEDGE;
        edge[pos+cols-1] = NOEDGE;
    }
    pos = (rows-1) * cols;
    for(c=0;c<cols;c++,pos++){
        edge[c] = NOEDGE;
        edge[pos] = NOEDGE;
    }

    /****************************************************************************
     * Compute the histogram of the magnitude image. Then use the histogram to
     * compute hysteresis thresholds.
     ****************************************************************************/
    for(r=0;r<32768;r++) hist[r] = 0;
    for(r=0,pos=0;r<rows;r++){
        for(c=0;c<cols;c++,pos++){
            if(edge[pos] == POSSIBLE_EDGE) hist[mag[pos]]++;
        }
    }

    /****************************************************************************
     * Compute the number of pixels that passed the nonmaximal suppression.
     ****************************************************************************/
    for(r=1,numedges=0;r<32768;r++){
        if(hist[r] != 0) maximum_mag = r;
        numedges += hist[r];
    }

    highcount = (int)(numedges * thigh + 0.5);

    /****************************************************************************
     * Compute the high threshold value as the (100 * thigh) percentage point
     * in the magnitude of the gradient histogram of all the pixels that passes
     * non-maximal suppression. Then calculate the low threshold as a fraction
     * of the computed high threshold value. John Canny said in his paper
     * "A Computational Approach to Edge Detection" that "The ratio of the
     * high to low threshold in the implementation is in the range two or three
     * to one." That means that in terms of this implementation, we should
     * choose tlow ~= 0.5 or 0.33333.
     ****************************************************************************/
    r = 1;
    numedges = hist[1];
    while((r<(maximum_mag-1)) && (numedges < highcount)){
        r++;
        numedges += hist[r];
    }
    highthreshold = r;
    lowthreshold = (int)(highthreshold * tlow + 0.5);
/*  
    if(VERBOSE){
        printf("The input low and high fractions of %f and %f computed to\n",
               tlow, thigh);
        printf("magnitude of the gradient threshold values of: %d %d\n",
               lowthreshold, highthreshold);
    }
*/  
    /****************************************************************************
     * This loop looks for pixels above the highthreshold to locate edges and
     * then calls follow_edges to continue the edge.
     ****************************************************************************/
    for(r=0,pos=0;r<rows;r++){
        for(c=0;c<cols;c++,pos++){
            if((edge[pos] == POSSIBLE_EDGE) && (mag[pos] >= highthreshold)){
                edge[pos] = EDGE;
                follow_edges((edge+pos), (mag+pos), lowthreshold, cols);
            }
        }
    }

    /****************************************************************************
     * Set all the remaining possible edges to non-edges.
     ****************************************************************************/
    for(r=0,pos=0;r<rows;r++){
        for(c=0;c<cols;c++,pos++) if(edge[pos] != EDGE) edge[pos] = NOEDGE;
    }
}

/*
tlow 0.20-0.50
thigh 0.60-0.90
*/
ImageWrapper *Image::cannyEdgeExtract(float tlow, float thigh) {
    int gx[3][3]={ 
        { -1, 0, 1 },
        { -2, 0, 2 },
        { -1, 0, 1 }};
    int gy[3][3]={
        {  1,  2,  1 },
        {  0,  0,  0 },
        { -1, -2, -1 }};
    int resultWidth=m_width-3;
    int resultHeight=m_height-3;
    int *diffx=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*resultHeight*resultWidth);
    int *diffy=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*resultHeight*resultWidth);
    int *mag=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*resultHeight*resultWidth);
    memset(diffx, 0, sizeof(int)*resultHeight*resultWidth);
    memset(diffy, 0, sizeof(int)*resultHeight*resultWidth);
    memset(mag, 0, sizeof(int)*resultHeight*resultWidth);

    // compute the magnitute and the angles in the image
    for(int y=0; y<m_height-3; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<m_width-3; x++) {
            int resultX=0;
            int resultY=0;
            for(int dy=0; dy<3; dy++) {
                for(int dx=0; dx<3; dx++) {
                    int pixel=(*this)[y+dy][x+dx];
                    resultX+=pixel*gx[dy][dx];
                    resultY+=pixel*gy[dy][dx];
                }
            }
            mag[y*resultWidth+x]=abs(resultX)+abs(resultY);
            diffx[y*resultWidth+x]=resultX;
            diffy[y*resultWidth+x]=resultY;
        }
    }
    uint8_t*nms=(uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*resultHeight*resultWidth);
    memset(nms, 0, sizeof(uint8_t)*resultHeight*resultWidth);
    non_max_supp(mag, diffx, diffy, resultHeight, resultWidth, nms);

    free(diffx);
    free(diffy);

    uint8_t *edge=(uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*resultHeight*resultWidth);
    memset(edge, 0, sizeof(uint8_t)*resultHeight*resultWidth);
    apply_hysteresis(mag, nms, resultHeight, resultWidth, tlow, thigh, edge);

    free(nms);
    free(mag);

    Image *result=new Image(edge, resultWidth, resultHeight, true);
    return [ImageWrapper imageWithCPPImage:result]; 
}

// rotate by 90, 180, 270, 360
ImageWrapper *Image::rotate(int angle) {
    Image* result;
    switch(angle) {
        case 90:
        case 270:
            result=new Image(m_height, m_width);
            break;
        case 180:
            result=new Image(m_width, m_height);
            break;
    }
    for(int y=0; y< m_height; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<m_width; x++) {
            switch(angle) {
                case 90:
                    (*result)[m_width-x-1][y]=(*this)[y][x];
                    break;
                case 180:
                    (*result)[m_height-y-1][x]=(*this)[y][x];
                    break;
                case 270:
                    (*result)[x][y]=(*this)[y][x];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return [ImageWrapper imageWithCPPImage:result];
}

ImageWrapper *Image::gaussianBlur() {
    int blur[5][5]={ 
        { 1, 4, 7, 4, 1 },
        { 4,16,26,16, 4 },
        { 7,26,41,26, 7 },
        { 4,16,26,16, 4 },
        { 1, 4, 7, 4, 1 }};

    Image *result=new Image(m_width-5, m_height-5);
    for(int y=0; y<m_height-5; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<m_width-5; x++) {
            int val=0;
            for(int dy=0; dy<5; dy++) {
                for(int dx=0; dx<5; dx++) {
                    int pixel=(*this)[y+dy][x+dx];
                    val+=pixel*blur[dy][dx];
                }
            }
            (*result)[y][x]=val/273;
        }
    }
    return [ImageWrapper imageWithCPPImage:result]; 
}


void Image::HistogramEqualisation() {
    std::vector<int> pdf(256);
    std::vector<int> cdf(256);
    // compute the pdf
    for(int i=0; i<m_height*m_width; i++) {
        pdf[m_imageData[i]]++;      
    }
    // compute the cdf
    cdf[0]=pdf[0];
    for(int i=1; i<256; i++) {
        cdf[i]=cdf[i-1]+pdf[i];
    }
    // now map the pixels to the new values
    for(int i=0; i<m_height*m_width; i++) {
        m_imageData[i]=255*cdf[m_imageData[i]]/cdf[255];
    }
}

UIImage *Image::toUIImage() {
    // generate space for the result
    uint8_t *result=(uint8_t *) calloc(m_width*m_height*sizeof(uint32_t),1);
    // process the image back to rgb
    for(int i=0; i<m_height*m_width; i++) {         
        result[i*4]=0;
        int val=m_imageData[i];
        result[i*4+1]=val;
        result[i*4+2]=val;
        result[i*4+3]=val;
    }
    // create a UIImage
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context=CGBitmapContextCreate(result, m_width, m_height, 8, m_width*sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little|kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
    CGImageRef image=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    UIImage *resultUIImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
    CGImageRelease(image);
    // make sure the data will be released by giving it to an autoreleased NSData
    [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:result length:m_width*m_height];
    return resultUIImage;
}

inline float Interpolate1(float a, float b, float c) {
    float mu=c-floor(c);
    return(a*(1-mu)+b*mu);
}

inline float Interpolate2(float a, float b, float c, float d, float x, float y)
{
    float ab = Interpolate1(a,b,x);
    float cd = Interpolate1(c,d,x);
    return Interpolate1(ab,cd,y);
}

ImageWrapper *Image::resize(int newX, int newY) {
    Image *result=new Image(newX, newY);
    for(float y=0; y<newY; y++) {
        for(float x=0; x<newX; x++) {
            float srcX0=x*(float)(m_width-1)/(float)newX;
            float srcY0=y*(float)(m_height-1)/(float)newY;
            float srcX1=(x+1)*(float)(m_width-1)/(float)newX;
            float srcY1=(y+1)*(float)(m_height-1)/(float)newY;
            float val=0,count=0;
            for(float srcY=srcY0; srcY<srcY1; srcY++) {
                for(float srcX=srcX0; srcX<srcX1; srcX++) {
                    val+=Interpolate2((*this)[(int)srcY][(int) srcX], (*this)[(int)srcY][(int) srcX+1],
                                      (*this)[(int)srcY+1][(int) srcX], (*this)[(int)srcY+1][(int) srcX+1],
                                      srcX, srcY);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            (*result)[(int) y][(int) x]=val/count;
        }
    }
    return [ImageWrapper imageWithCPPImage:result];
}

void Image::findLargestStructure(std::vector<ImagePoint> *maxPoints) {
    // process the image
    std::vector<ImagePoint> points;
    points.reserve(10000);
    for(int y=0; y<m_height; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<m_width; x++) {
            // if we've found a point in the image then extract everything connected to it
            if((*this)[y][x]!=0) {
                extractConnectedRegion(x, y, &points);
                if(points.size()>maxPoints->size()) {
                    maxPoints->clear();
                    maxPoints->resize(points.size());
                    std::copy(points.begin(), points.end(), maxPoints->begin());
                } 
                points.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}

int findHeightAtX(Image *img, int x) {  
    // find the top most set pixel
    bool foundTop;
    int topY=0;
    for(;topY<img->getHeight(); topY++) {
        if((*img)[topY][x]==0) {
            foundTop=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(foundTop) {
        // find the bottom most set pixel
        int bottomY=img->getHeight()-1;
        for(;bottomY>0 && (*img)[bottomY][x]==0; bottomY--);
        return bottomY-topY;
    }
    return -1;
}

void Image::skeletonise() {
    bool changes=true;
    while(changes) {
        changes=false;
        for(int y=1; y<m_height-1; y++) {
            for(int x=1; x<m_width-1; x++) {
                if((*this)[y][x]!=0) {
                    bool val[8];
                    val[0]=(*this)[y-1][x-1]!=0;
                    val[1]=(*this)[y-1][x]!=0;
                    val[2]=(*this)[y-1][x+1]!=0;
                    val[3]=(*this)[y][x+1]!=0;
                    val[4]=(*this)[y+1][x+1]!=0;
                    val[5]=(*this)[y+1][x]!=0;
                    val[6]=(*this)[y+1][x-1]!=0;
                    val[7]=(*this)[y][x-1]!=0;

                    bool remove=false;
                    for(int i=0; i<7 && !remove;i++) {
                        remove=(val[(0+i)%8] && val[(1+i)%8] && val[(7+i)%8] && val[(6+i)%8] && val[(5+i)%8] && !(val[(2+i)%8] || val[(3+i)%8] || val[(4+i)%8]))
                                || (val[(0+i)%8] && val[(1+i)%8] && val[(7+i)%8] && !(val[(3+i)%8] || val[(6+i)%8] || val[(5+i)%8] || val[(4+i)%8])) ||
                                !(val[(0+i)%8] || val[(1+i)%8] || val[(2+i)%8]  || val[(3+i)%8]  || val[(4+i)%8]  || val[(5+i)%8]  || val[(6+i)%8] || val[(7+i)%8]);
                    }
                    if(remove) {
                        (*this)[y][x]=0;
                        changes=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankit Srivastava

Answer (score 1):

The Tesseract engine by itself does not give very good results unless you apply some image pre-processing to the image...

here is what I did and achieved almost 95% accuracy...

convert the UIImage to greyscale and apply autoLocalThreshold to the image.. for this I used a  class I found on the net.. and also keep in mind if you are resizing the image you maintain the aspect ratio and the image editing code is correct because there is lot of code which can corrupt the image without you knowing it.. so here is some code if it helps you..

Image Class to convert the greyscale and autolocalthreshold...

```
/*
 *  Image.h
 *  ImageProcessing
 *
 * 
 *
 */

#import <UIKit/UIImage.h>

#include <vector>

class Image;
// objective C wrapper for our image class
@interface ImageWrapper : NSObject {
    Image *image;
    bool ownsImage;
}

@property(assign, nonatomic) Image *image;
@property(assign, nonatomic) bool ownsImage;
+ (ImageWrapper *) imageWithCPPImage:(Image *) theImage;

@end

class ImagePoint {
public:
    short x,y;
    inline ImagePoint(short xpos, short ypos) {
        x=xpos;
        y=ypos;
    }
    inline ImagePoint(int xpos, int ypos) {
        x=xpos;
        y=ypos;
    }
    inline ImagePoint(const ImagePoint &other) {
        x=other.x;
        y=other.y;
    }
    inline ImagePoint() {
        x=0; y=0;
    }
};

class Image {
private:
    uint8_t *m_imageData;
    uint8_t **m_yptrs;
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
    bool m_ownsData;
    Image(ImageWrapper *other, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    Image(int width, int height);
    Image(uint8_t *imageData, int width, int height, bool ownsData=false);
    Image(UIImage *srcImage, int width, int height, CGInterpolationQuality interpolation, bool imageIsRotatedBy90degrees=false);
    void initYptrs();
public:
    // copy a section of another image
    static ImageWrapper *createImage(ImageWrapper *other, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    // create an empty image of the required width and height
    static ImageWrapper *createImage(int width, int height);
    // create an image from data
    static ImageWrapper *createImage(uint8_t *imageData, int width, int height, bool ownsData=false);
    // take a source UIImage and convert it to greyscale
    static ImageWrapper *createImage(UIImage *srcImage, int width, int height, bool imageIsRotatedBy90degrees=false);
    // edge detection
    ImageWrapper *cannyEdgeExtract(float tlow, float thigh);
    // local thresholding
    ImageWrapper* autoLocalThreshold();
    // threshold using integral
    ImageWrapper *autoIntegratingThreshold();
    // threshold an image automatically
    ImageWrapper *autoThreshold();
    // gaussian smooth the image
    ImageWrapper *gaussianBlur();
    // get the percent set pixels
    int getPercentSet();
    // exrtact a connected area from the image
    void extractConnectedRegion(int x, int y, std::vector<ImagePoint> *points);
    // find the largest connected region in the image
    void findLargestStructure(std::vector<ImagePoint> *maxPoints);
    // normalise an image
    void normalise();
    // rotate by 90, 180, 270, 360
    ImageWrapper *rotate(int angle);
    // shrink to a new size
    ImageWrapper *resize(int newX, int newY);
    ImageWrapper *shrinkBy2();
    // histogram equalisation
    void HistogramEqualisation();
    // skeltonize
    void skeletonise();
    // convert back to a UIImage for display
    UIImage *toUIImage();
    ~Image() {
        if(m_ownsData)
            free(m_imageData);
        delete m_yptrs;
    }
    inline uint8_t* operator[](const int rowIndex) {
        return m_yptrs[rowIndex];
    }
    inline int getWidth() {
        return m_width;
    }
    inline int getHeight() {
        return m_height;
    }
};

inline bool sortByX1(const ImagePoint &p1, const ImagePoint &p2) {
    if(p1.x==p2.x) return p1.y<p2.y;
    return p1.x<p2.x;
}

inline bool sortByY1(const ImagePoint &p1, const ImagePoint &p2) {
    if(p1.y==p2.y) return p1.x<p2.x;
    return p1.y<p2.y;
}
```

and here is how you use it...

```
    [imageProcessing startTesseract];

    UIImage *newImage = [imageProcessing resizeImage:image];
    ImageWrapper *greyScale=Image::createImage(newImage, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height);


    ImageWrapper *edges=greyScale.image->autoLocalThreshold();
    // show the results

    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[imageProcessing ocrImage:edges.image->toUIImage()]] ;
```

here the imageProcessing contains methods to start Tesseract and other related functions...

```
// METHOD TO DECODE THE MICR COMPONENTS USING TESSETACT

- (NSString *) ocrImage: (UIImage *) capturedImage
{

    CGSize imageSize = [capturedImage size];
    double bytes_per_line   = CGImageGetBytesPerRow([capturedImage CGImage]);
    double bytes_per_pixel  = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel([capturedImage CGImage]) / 8.0;

    CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider([capturedImage CGImage]));
    const UInt8 *imageData = CFDataGetBytePtr(data);
    imageThresholder = new tesseract::ImageThresholder();       

    imageThresholder->SetImage(imageData,(int) imageSize.width,(int) imageSize.height,(int)bytes_per_pixel,(int)bytes_per_line);

    // CONVERTING THE IMAGE INTO PIXELS


    objForTesseract->SetImage(imageThresholder->GetPixRectGrey());

    // GET THE DECODED TEXT
    objForTesseract->Recognize(NULL);

    char* text = objForTesseract->GetUTF8Text();

    CFRelease(data);

    delete imageThresholder;
    imageThresholder=nil;
    objForTesseract->End();
    delete objForTesseract;
    objForTesseract=nil;


    return [NSString stringWithCString:text encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

I will submit the .mm for image as separate answer...

Comment: what is this ImageThresholder  ?

Comment: @Ankit Srivastava Any hints on this code or how to use it? 
I've tried to paste it into files and then import it into my project it's results with many errors.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer in FAQ in Tesseract.Read the question:[Is there a Minimum Text Size? (It won't read screen text!)](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#Is_there_a_Minimum_Text_Size?_%28It_won%27t_read_screen_text!%29).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will show accurate output for any resolution. I was trying yesterday the same thing. I grabbed image from camera for high resolution image. I also uploaded low resolution image from photo library. But it didn't worked. I guess you need to make some more search here.
Please see if [**OCR Api Service**](http://ocrapiservice.com/) can help you. You can try out [**this**](https://github.com/smart-mobile-software/ocrapiservice) demo. There is some credential issue in the demo. You need to provide one. But I am not sure which credentials are required. Check if this can help you.