# How to recognise the accurate text from an image using Tesseract OCR Library in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ocr, tesseract

I am creating an iPhone application in Objective C. I am trying to recognise the text from an image (taken from camera). For this, I use in my app Tesseract OCR Library. Its working fine for some of the text but not getting accurate results from the captured image. Also have the latest tessdata file from Google code.

I added tesseract library from [this link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/93276/implementing-tesseract-ocr-ios).

Below is my image that I tried to recognise :

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
    G8Tesseract *tesseract = [[G8Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng+fra" engineMode:G8OCREngineModeTesseractCubeCombined];
    [tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:;,.!-()#&÷" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
    tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = G8PageSegmentationModeAuto;
    tesseract.maximumRecognitionTime = 60.0;
    tesseract.image = [selectedImage g8_blackAndWhite];
    [tesseract recognize];

    NSLog(@"%@", [tesseract recognizedText]);
```

But I am getting results like this :

```
BAZAAR

mm; l Savees l smmamm l mm; l Accessories

commemw Street ' _ . «mm. me o snwapnagay

www minabazaav.cum
```

I already go through from this links:

- [How do I get accurate text using Tesseract OCR in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398351/how-do-i-get-accurate-text-using-tesseract-ocr-in-ios)
- [Why Tesseract OCR library (iOS) cannot recognize text at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169148/why-tesseract-ocr-library-ios-cannot-recognize-text-at-all)
- http://www.scriptscoop2.com/t/42247286510f/c-3.5-why-i-am-not-able-to-recognize-text-in-image-using-tesseract.html.

Do any one else experience the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case Tesseract Library was not accurate most of the time. instead [Abby](https://www.abbyy.com/ocr-sdk/) was kind of ok. but abby is not offline

[Abby Stackoverflow Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abbyy)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @iDev, using ABBYY I got the accurate text from my captured image. Can you please suggest me whether I can get separate each text with respect to name, address, email, phone number etc using this?

Comment: `http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processBusinessCard` with this api you will get separate values that you expect

Comment: this is proper have a look at this  http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processBusinessCard/

Comment: Thanks again for your time..!